# Automapper: How do I map Lazy<TFrom> to TTo?

Tags: c#, automapper

I need to map a list of `Lazy<TFrom>` to a list of `TTo`.  What I've done isn't working - I only get null values.  Without the `Lazy<>` wrapper it works perfectly. What am I doing wrong?

```
// Map this list
// It's passed in as an argument and has all the data
IList<Lazy<Employee>> employees

public static IList<TTo> MapList(IList<Lazy<TFrom>> fromModel)
        {
            Mapper.CreateMap<Lazy<TFrom>, TTo>();// Is this needed?
            return Mapper.Map<IList<Lazy<TFrom>>, IList<TTo>>(fromModel);

            // This doesn't work
            // return Mapper.Map<IList<TTo>>(fromModel.Select(x => x.Value));
        }

// Maps the child classes
Mapper.CreateMap<Lazy<Employee>, EmployeeDTO>()
                .ForMember(x => x.AccidentDTO, i => i.MapFrom(model => model.Value.GetAccident()))
                .ForMember(x => x.CriticalIllnessDTO, i => i.MapFrom(model =>                 model.Value.GetCriticalIllness()))
                .ForMember(x => x.ValidationMessages, i => i.MapFrom(model => model.Value.ValidationMessages));

// Returns nulls !!!
var dataDTO = MyMapper<Lazy<Employee>, EmployeeDTO>.MapList(employees);
```

Comment: Can you include the code for setting `employees` both with and without `Lazy`? Possibly you are losing scope on something by the (delayed) time that the `Lazy` call is made.

Comment: Looks like this blog post might have some answers for you, if you can read it through all the horrendous formatting. http://softwareprojectmusings.blogspot.com/2010/07/custom-resolvers-for-automapper-to-use.html

Comment: @MikeGuthrie...It's passed in as an argument and has all the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I've done to solve my problem.  If someone has a better idea, please let me know and I'll mark it as the answer.

```
// Get the Values of the Lazy<Employee> items and use the result for mapping
var nonLazyEmployees = employees.Select(i => i.Value).ToList();
var dataDTO = MyMapper<Employee, EmployeeDTO>.MapList(nonLazyEmployees);

public static IList<TTo> MapList(IList<Lazy<TFrom>> fromModel)
{
     Mapper.CreateMap<Lazy<TFrom>, TTo>();
     return Mapper.Map<IList<Lazy<TFrom>>, IList<TTo>>(fromModel);
}

// Maps the child classes
Mapper.CreateMap<Employee, EmployeeDTO>()
     .ForMember(x => x.AccidentDTO, i => i.MapFrom(model => model.GetAccident()))
     .ForMember(x => x.CriticalIllnessDTO, i => i.MapFrom(model => model.GetCriticalIllness()))
     .ForMember(x => x.ValidationMessages, i => i.MapFrom(model => model.ValidationMessages));
```